# how to track dlls being loaded into a process?

Tags: .net, unmanaged, dllimport

I am looking for a tool to trace the dlls being loaded into a process on windows. The app i have is loading managed and unmanaged dlls, but not sure if the managed ones are loading the unmaanged ones. Process Explorer and File Explorer doesn't seem to help much. Any thoughts?? thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is the best tool I know of, though its level of detail can be overwhelming.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2.0, [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) can do [dynamic application profiling](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/application_profiling.htm).  This allows you to see what modules a running application is loading, as opposed to just seeing what is in the static import tables.