# How to find out why a DLL fails to load in different programs?

Tags: c, windows, dll, rust

**Question in general**

Is there some way to find out why a DLL fails to load in a program? I periodically bump into errors while loading DLLs in both my and 3rd party software. It'd be nice to have common way to solve this situations and determine what is wrong with the specific DLL on a specific system.

**For example**

I've compiled a simple DLL with Rust (x64, MSVC ABI):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn test_dll_call() -> u8 {
    let mut f = File::create("C:\\test.txt").unwrap();
    f.write(b"Hello, world!").unwrap();
    return 0
}
```

It's built via:

```
cargo build --release
```

DependencyWalker shows a lot of API-MS-WIN-CORE-* DLLs missing in my system for the compiled DLL:

- API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPINIT-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-ATOMS-L1-1-0.DLL
- ...

However on my Windows 10 x64 system I've already installed MS Visual Studio 2015 and MS C++ Redistributables 2005, 2010, 2012, 2013 and 2015.

A lot of DLLs with missing dependencies in DependencyWalker work fine, so I've tried to use my DLL in Lua:

```
require("test");

function main()
    test.test_dll_call();
end
```

However I get laconic error *"loop or previous error loading module 'test'"*. Some other 3rd party DLLs have loaded like a charm. How do I check what is wrong with my DLL?

Comment: Why is this tagged C? There is no C here.

Comment: In my example Rusl compiles dll with C abi. And as I understand Windows C professionals understand structure of dll file better than others.

Comment: In pure C Winapi it would have been trivial, just call `GetLastError`. But I'm guessing you can't do that, since you seem to have ten or so abstraction layers between the API and the application...

Comment: Have you tried [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)? Potentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3722087/155423.

Comment: Yes, I've tried ProcessMonitor: [several DLLs failed to load](http://pastebin.com/LCYRJDmB). The most strange is 整瑳搮汬.DLL. But how to find out exact problem?